Cherry pick a range of commits, ignoring all that cause conflicts
I am trying to apply a range of commits from one branch to another but would like to drop every commit that causes conflicts. My understanding is that merge strategies work on the individual conflicts but in my case it's crucial that if there is any conflict in a commit, it needs to drop that entire commit.
Does anybody know of a way to do this in a single command with git? Right now I'm cherry picking each commit individually and then abort the cherry pick if there's a conflict and then continue with the next commit. That's relatively slow though, so I wonder if there's a faster way to do this.

What is the use case for this? Conflicts are often benign and normal. Perhaps there is a better solution.

You can pick a range of commits with git cherry-pick from..to and then git cherry-pick --skip when a conflict occurs.

You could even write a long bash 1-liner that can cycle through failures until it succeeds.

It might help if you explain how you know it makes sense to do this. (It also might not help, but the ask is strange enough that I can't stop trying to figure out why you might want to do this rather than actually thinking of solutions.)

Say someone commits something that unfortunately prevents me from compiling because I don't have a new dependency that's required. In order to work on an urgent patch, I'd rather simply back out everything requiring this dependency than having to first get this dependency. Especially if that dependency is in an area that has nothing to do with what I'm working on. So I want to revert the original patch plus everything that touched that same area afterwards.
